# Testing DataContractSerializer with String

Tags: .net, wcf, datacontractserializer

I'm testing sending a complex message object over a WCF service and getting various serialization errors. In order to simplify things I'm trying to cut it down to just testing the `DataContractSerializer`, for which I've written the following test based on the code [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
Dim message As TLAMessage = MockFactory.GetMessage
Dim dcs As DataContractSerializer = New DataContractSerializer(GetType(TLAMessage))
Dim xml As String = String.Empty

Using stream As New StringWriter(), writer As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stream)
    dcs.WriteObject(writer, message)
    xml = stream.ToString
End Using

Debug.Print(xml)

Dim newMessage As TLAMessage
Dim sr As New StringReader(xml)
Dim reader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(sr)
dcs = New DataContractSerializer(GetType(TLAMessage))
newMessage = CType(dcs.ReadObject(reader, True), TLAMessage) 'Error here
reader.Close()
sr.Close()

Assert.IsTrue(newMessage IsNot Nothing)
```

However this gets an unusual error in itself on the call to `ReadObject`: `Unexpected end of file while parsing Name has occurred. Line 1, position 6144`

It appears to be a buffering error but I can't see how to 'ReadToEnd' on the string. I've tried using a `MemoryStream`: `Dim ms As New MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml))` and a `StreamWriter` but each of those has come with their own errors or are not compatible with the `ReadObject` method of the `DataContractSerializer` which takes a variety of different overloads.

Note that adapting the code from the MSDN page works fine but requires serializing to a file, however I wanted to serialize to and from a string but I think that I'm missing something vital.

Am I missing something obvious in the code above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data from your `XmlWriter` is not immediately populated to the underlying `StringWriter`. So you should flush the writer after writing:

```
dcs.WriteObject(writer, message)
writer.Flush()
xml = stream.ToString()
```

Comment: So obvious and I'd been looking in the wrong place all along. Thanks